# Converting a PHP script into a JavaScript script which reads and prints XML data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xml

I am trying to replace all of my PHP with JS (Node and ajax (and jQuery library)) but am having trouble converting the following PHP script into an ajax engine.

```
    <?php
    $xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc->load("Administration/data/people.xml");

    $xx=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('person');

    $hintt="";
    for($ii=0; $ii<($xx->length); $ii++)
      {
      $yy=$xx->item($ii)->getElementsByTagName('id');
      $zz=$xx->item($ii)->getElementsByTagName('fullName');
      if ($yy->item(0)->nodeType==1)
        {

            echo "<button type='button' class='mybutton' name='users'>" .
            $zz->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</button>";

        }
      }

    ?>
```

Here is my ajax attempt:

```
        <div id="loadMe">
            <h1>Reading..</h1>
        </div>

        <script>
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "Administration/data/people.xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function(xml) {
                        $(xml).find('person').each(function(){
                            var fullName = $(this).attr('fullName');
                            $("<button type=button class=mybutton value='+fullName+'></button>").html("<h3>'+fullName+'</h3>").appendTo('#loadMe');
                        });
                    }
                });
        </script>
```

To me, it looks pretty similar, but the JS is not working. Anyone see an inconsistency or can tell me why my XML elements are not appending to the indicated div tag? Thanks a lot in advance guys and gals!

EDIT (1/24/14 1:24 AM):
I thought providing my XML would be helpful, perhaps I am referencing the data wrong?

```
<people>
  <person>
    <id>10</id>
    <fullName>Philadelphia Collins</fullName>
    <firstName>Philadelphia</firstName>
    <lastName>Collins</lastName>
    <age>62</age>
    <hometown>Sunnyvale</hometown>
    <job>Restraunt Owner</job>
  </person>
<people>
```

Comment: you  should do `.done()` and `.fail()` instead of just `success:`

Comment: The line beginning `$('<button type='button'` needs to use double-quotes inside the string. You should have seen an error in your browser's console about this.

Comment: I used both but this is not the cause of the problem. @Blazemonger do you see any logical errors?

Comment: Also, your `<script>` should be moved to the bottom of the page or wrapped in a `$(document).ready` call.

Comment: Guys, sorry about the messy syntax, I've fixed all the little stuff... But there is a bigger problem, logically. Isn't there? I must have my logic wrong, anyone?

Comment: @blazemonger please have another look if you don't mind.

Comment: Ilan Biala @Ilan, please have another look, I've cleaned up my syntax. Thanks!

Comment: This script is run *after* jquery has been loaded, correct? That could be the issue; what do your devtools/javascript console say?

Comment: Something like this is better...http://codepen.io/nbatothemax/pen/AbCyd You should try to provide some sort of indication about any errors, and also `dataType` is usually automatically set by jQuery, but if you need to you can set it to `xml`. Do you have a page where this is running and we can do some debugging?

Comment: @Ilan Biala great JS, I tried your solution, but I am not getting any output or errors, perhaps I am not reference the XML child nodes correctly. I edited my question to include my XML structure, could you take a look once more? Thanks again!

Comment: @blazemonger, I am not getting any errors or output, therefore I think that now it is not a problem with the JS but with the XML structure, I added the XML to my answer if you could take another quick look. Thanks!

Comment: your XML ending `<people>` tag is missing a closing slash. It should be `</people>`.

Answer (score 0):

I've set up a [test page](http://ilanbiala.com/test/) that you can try and play around with if at any time you need to do more exploring. So here comes the solution.

First, I tried doing an AJAX request, which always came back as failed because the XML was invalid. If I just tried to access the XML, it said it was not valid and could not be displayed. The issue was the closing `<people>` tag was missing a `/`. It should be `</people>'. So that fixed the AJAX request failing. The next part was parsing the XML response. I did this by using the`.children()`method in jQuery and then getting the text of the element with`.text()`. It ends up looking something like this:

```
var fullName = $(this).children('fullName').text();
```

So with all that and anything else I may have missed but is available at the test page, I hope you can fix your issue and get a successful AJAX request going. If I missed anything or I wasn't clear, let me know and I'll try to explain a little more.

By the way, doing `console.log();` in Chrome DevTools and using breakpoints to access the data myself always helps me see what I'm working with, that way I know how to go about getting what data I want from a request.

Good luck!